# Parentesis en negritas (Visual basic)

Tags: excel, vba

Me preguntaba si existe una opción en Visual Basic que te marque en negritas el paréntesis que estas cerrando como lo hacen muchos otros IDE´s, ya que es fácil perderse sin esta ayuda

GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

No, no se puede.

Dentro del editor de VBA, si pinchas en HERRAMIENTAS->OPCIONES, puedes configurar aspectos visuales del editor, pero está muy limitado. En concreto, lo que tú pides no se puede hacer. Tendrás que acostumbrarte a trabajar así me temo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]